# Getting rid of Assembly with TagPrefix in .NET 3.5

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5, .net-assembly, app-code

I had to change my .NET 3.5 web site to a web project, so I needed to remove the App_Code folder but found that I still have these:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="App_Code" Namespace="MyNamespace" TagPrefix="pf" %>
```

What's the simplest way to get rid of this?  I tried renaming the assembly to the projectName.dll but that crashes.

Any ideas?

Comment: What was the content of the `App_Code` folder?

Comment: nothing now, as App_Code got changed to Old_App_Code since App_Code doesn't exist in Web Application projects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use this:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="YourAssemblyName" Namespace="YourNewNamespace" TagPrefix="pf" %>
```

Regarding a `Web Application` Microsoft [says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730880%28VS.80%29.aspx#wapp_topic5):

*All code-behind class files and stand-alone class files in the project are compiled into a single assembly, which is placed in the Bin folder. Because this is a single assembly, you can specify attributes such as assembly name and version, as well as the location of the output assembly.*

So now you should have a unique assembly.

Comment: hmm the new folder is just another folder, how do i turn it into an assembly though?

Comment: cool, yes i did that but it broke because I didn't rebuild the project and check it in the debugger. Works fine now. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

The original idea behind app_code was that code could be dropped in at any time and consumed by the web application. This is a problem because it doesn't really show up in a normal project. So to convert you need to take the code found in app_code and convert into one or more class libraries and include in your web project. when this build's correctly, change the register assembly tags to point at the new .dll file(s).

Comment: I saw the second comment as I was writing this one. if nothing is in app_code anymore just change the name of the assembly to reflect where the code was moved to..